# Subgroups of the multiplicative group $(\Bbb C^{\times},\cdot)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have $n\ge 2$ and have to show $U(n):=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\; z^n=1\}$ is  subgroup of the multiplicative group $(\Bbb C^{\times},\cdot)$.

I can t understand the problem, help please.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Tobias U (n) part, how I can demonstrate it is a subgroup?

Comment: Do you know what a subgroup is?

Comment: Yes it has to form a group with *

Comment: Ok, so you need to prove that this is a group. Where are you having trouble with that?

Comment: Hibe me please one example how I prove asociative and the rest I will do it muself please

Comment: @Darius: Multiplication in $\Bbb C^*$ is associative, by definition of a group, so it is associative in $U(n).$

Comment: Ok but what I have to do with the condition z^n=1?

Comment: If you include your thoughts and efforts, you'll find that people here will be more than happy to help you refine/fix/complete your proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a subset $S$ of a group is a subgroup you need to show:

1. $1\in S$.
2. For $x,y \in S$ one has $xy \in S$.
3. For $x \in S$ one has $x^{-1} \in S$.

One can combine these into "the set $S$ is non-empty and for $x,y \in S$ one has $xy^{-1}\in S$" but let us stick to the three points.

The first point is quite obvious, but write it down. For the second  note $(xy)^n= x^n y^n$ and it becomes easy. For the third, note $1= 1^n = (xx^{-1})^n = x^n (x^{-1})^n = (x^{-1})^n $.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$\bullet\;\; U_n\subseteq\Bbb C^{\times}$ is clear

$\bullet\;\;1\in U_n$

$\bullet\;\;$ given $a,b\in U_n$, you need to prove that $ab^{-1}$ stays in $U_n$ as well.

Observe that, being $\Bbb C^{\times}$ group, the inverse is well defined.